# NodeModules\serve-static\index.js Error :48

Tags: node.js, express

can anyone help me on this error please:-

> Image of the error line :https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xqgh6.png

> Image of the server :https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1e1t.png

Comment: Please add your code and error messages as text in the post. That will make it easier to write answers.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: Apologies, my initial answer was inaccurate, as I was looking at the wrong image.*

Per the [express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html), the proper syntax for setting your server's virtual path for static files is as follows:

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

Check line 9 in your app.js code, as you appear to be passing 2 arguments into express.static.

Comment: Is it okay to change node module??

Comment: @SupratimPurkait, no, changes in node_modules will be overridden next time you install or update the package. Your error appears to come from using a string as the second argument of `express.static` when it expects an object.

Answer (score 0):

@MForMarlon: This is not gonna work if options are `Not_An_Object_Or_Null` as the error suggests, which mean if you assign options = a number/string, anything that's not an Object or null (aka primitive), the check in your answer won't be able to prevent the error.

@Supratim Purkait: you can add a `console.log` statement before line 48 to see the options value you are passing to the function - as the error say: it is not an object nor null.
And the way you create an object from options looks weird. Normally you just do: opts = options || {};

So to resolve this issue, make sure options is an object or null first.